# Dell E6430 TouchPad Stopped Working

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad

At some point in the last week, my touchpad stopped working.  I say "some point" because I normally use a mouse, except once a week, when I use the touchpad.

In the settings GUI, I no longer even have a touchpad tab.

How can I get this working again?  I guess the first step is determining what I have.  But I don't think this command tells me much.

Do I need to reboot and go into my BIOS?

```
buck@buck-Latitude-E6430 ~]$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101d   id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_E4HD             id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard                    id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard                    id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
[buck@buck-Latitude-E6430 ~]$
```

Comment: You should update your answer to provide more information, like your Ubuntu version and architecture. Also check if you get any output from `grep -i Touchpad /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` that could help diagnose your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Nothing is returned from the grep you suggested.  This is Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

Comment: I had a similar problem, fixed it following the instructions in this blog: http://resalxh.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/ubuntu-12-04-lts-x64-the-next-step-getting-touchpad-working/